# Using Devise and Facebook to Authenticate User with certain permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've got this app, and the Devise + Facebook authentication works but I keep getting error 403 stating that I need Facebook or Koala "read_stream" permissions.

No in my dev box it worked fine the way I've had it, putting it into production and letting other users in that's where the problem became. Now I've got the following setup in;

**/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# ==> OmniAuth
config.omniauth :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :scope => 'email,user_actions.news,user_likes,read_stream,user_about_me,user_friends'
```

**/models/user.rb**

```
def facebook

  access_token = self.authorizations.where(:provider => 'facebook').collect(&:token).first
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)

end
```

**but doing;**

```
User.current.facebook.get_connection('me', 'home')
```

**gives me error;**

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError (type: OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream [HTTP 403]):
```

did something change since my release? why does dev work fine with the above scopes and production gives errors. Same code, nothing changed.

Comment: Does it error in production for you or for other users? Have you gotten read_stream permission approved? You are aware that you will not get it approved?

Comment: Works for me, but other users get the 200 error, `Requires extended permission: read_stream`.... why wouldn't I get it approved?

Comment: Because https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2 say so. And the reason you get an error is that the permission is not approved by Facebook

Comment: I see, alright so from the sounds of it and documentation, my app account or setup in Facebook has to be reviewed before my app can request. So my setup might be correct its just Facebook is denying my apps request because I didn't have it reviewed. Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: Correct. You can ask anyone that have a role in the app for any permission but it you are going to ask other people you need to get the permission approved first

Comment: That would explain it :) Thanks!